# Bash script with loop from a file

Tags: bash, curl

A bash script reads a file with several lines and two columns each line, parses it into variables that will be used in a `curl` command.

file.txt:

```
abc def
ghi jkl
```

Curl command:

`curl -X GET "https://api.uat.example.com/api/v1/status?first=${FIRST_COLUMN}&second=${SECOND_COLUMN}`

Desired output:

`curl -X GET "https://api.uat.example.com/api/v1/status?first=abc&second=def`

`curl -X GET "https://api.uat.example.com/api/v1/status?first=ghi&second=jkl`

And do a loop until there are no more rows to read in file.txt.

Comment: `while read first second _; do curl -X GET "https://api.uat.example.com/api/v1/status?first=$first&second=$second"; done < file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each column has 2 words separated by space, then you can do something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while read first second
do
     curl -X GET "https://api.uat.example.com/api/v1/status?first=$first&second=$second"
done < "<file_path>"
```